# Are deamons binding to 0.0.0.0 (INADDR_ANY) also capable of receiving packets from interfaces without an IP?

Tags: linux, networking, udp, ip

Are deamons binding to 0.0.0.0 (`INADDR_ANY`) also capable of receiving UDP packets from interfaces without an IP?

For example if a deamon listens on 0.0.0.0:514 (UDP) will it receive packets from eth1 even if eth1 doesn't have a configured IP address?

Some sites claim `INADDR_ANY` binds to interfaces while others claim it only binds to *all* addresses.

Comment: I don't think an interface can be enabled if it doesn't have an address.

Comment: How can you possibly expect to receive anything from an interface that nobody can *send* to? Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: By having a static ARP and a static MAC entry on a switch it's very well possible that the traffic will be sent to the right host.

Comment: ARP in your computer is a table for MACS and IPS, ARP on a switch is for MAC and PORT of the switch. For UDP packages an IP address is needed if not the package is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

> Are deamons binding to 0.0.0.0 (INADDR_ANY) also capable of receiving UDP packets from interfaces without an IP?

No, the UDP datagram requires an IP address. We have other protocols that works whith out IP addresses like IPX.

> For example if a deamon listens on 0.0.0.0:514 (UDP) will it receive packets from eth1 even if eth1 doesn't have a configured IP address?

When the deamon or services listen to 0.0.0.0 it is listening on all IP addresses that you have. The 0.0.0.0 is an IP address that represents all of them, by saying this is your python script have a configured IP address.

If your interface does not have an IP address how other devices know where to send a package? In your local network you may receive broadcast packages that are sent to all host on your network, but outside your local network you are not going to receive anything. Routers route traffic based on IP addresses (OSI LAYER 3).

> Some sites claim INADDR_ANY binds to interfaces while others claim it only binds to all addresses

From [the Python sockets documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html):

> For IPv4 addresses, two special forms are accepted instead of a host address: `''` represents `INADDR_ANY`, which is used to bind to all interfaces, and the string `'<broadcast>'` represents `INADDR_BROADCAST`. This behavior is not compatible with IPv6, therefore, you may want to avoid these if you intend to support IPv6 with your Python programs.